# Pandas setting a value depending on date ranges on another dataframe with merge and insert null for non-matching rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

This is a follow-up question to this post:
[Pandas setting a value depending on date ranges on another dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72499666/pandas-setting-a-value-depending-on-date-ranges-on-another-dataframe/)

If there are rows in the transactions dataframe that don't have a matching agentname in the rate dataframe, how can we still keep those rows but put in a null/na value for the agentname_rates column?

Rates table

```
   Agentname   ProductType     OldRate NewRate StartDate   EndDate
   0   VSFAAL      SPORTS       0.0    10.0    2020-11-05  2021-01-18
   1   VSFAAL      APPAREL      0.0    35.0    2020-11-05  2022-05-03
   2   VSFAAL      SPORTS      10.0    15.0    2021-01-18  2022-05-03
   3   VSFAALJS    SPORTS       0.0    10.0    2020-11-07  2022-05-03
   4   VSFAALJS    APPAREL      0.0    15.0    2020-11-07  2021-11-09
   5   VSFAALJS    APPAREL     15.0     5.0    2021-11-09  2022-05-03
```

Transactions table

```
   Date                         Sales   Agentname   ProductType     
   0 2020-12-01 08:00:02        100.0  VSFAAL      SPORTS       
   1 2022-03-01 08:00:09         99.0  VSFAAL      APPAREL      
   2 2022-03-01 08:00:14         75.0  VSFAAL      SPORTS       
   3 2021-05-01 08:00:39         67.0  VSFAALJS    SPORTS 
   4 2020-05-01 08:00:56         160.0 VSFAALJS    APPAREL           
   5 2021-05-01 08:00:56         65.0  VSFAALJS    APPAREL 
   6 2021-06-03 09:07:33         55.0  VSRANDOM    SPORTS
```

Desired Output

```
              Date              Sales   Agentname   ProductType     Agentname_rates
   0 2020-12-01 08:00:02        100.0  VSFAAL      SPORTS             10.0
   1 2022-03-01 08:00:09         99.0  VSFAAL      APPAREL            35.0
   2 2022-03-01 08:00:14         75.0  VSFAAL      SPORTS             15.0
   3 2021-05-01 08:00:39         67.0  VSFAALJS    SPORTS             10.0
   4 2020-05-01 08:00:56         160.0 VSFAALJS    APPAREL              NULL
   5 2021-05-01 08:00:56         65.0  VSFAALJS    APPAREL            15.0
   6 2021-06-03 09:07:33         55.0  VSRANDOM    SPORTS             NULL
```

The following code merges the two tables but does not retain have the two rows with null that I want to keep.

```
df3=df2.merge(df[['StartDate', 'EndDate','NewRate']], 
         left_on =[df2['Agentname'], df2['ProductType']],
         right_on=[df['Agentname'],  df['ProductType']],
              how='left',
          suffixes=('','_start')
        ).drop(columns=['key_0', 'key_1' ])

df3[df3['Date'].astype('datetime64').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').between(
                                      df3['StartDate'].astype('datetime64'),
                                      df3['EndDate'].astype('datetime64'))
   ]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use left join with remove `StartDate/EndDate` columns:

```
df3 = df2.merge(df3.drop(['StartDate','EndDate'], axis=1), how='left')
print (df3)
                  Date  Sales Agentname ProductType  NewRate
0  2020-12-01 08:00:02  100.0    VSFAAL      SPORTS     10.0
1  2022-03-01 08:00:09   99.0    VSFAAL     APPAREL     35.0
2  2022-03-01 08:00:14   75.0    VSFAAL      SPORTS     15.0
3  2021-05-01 08:00:39   67.0  VSFAALJS      SPORTS     10.0
4  2020-05-01 08:00:56  160.0  VSFAALJS     APPAREL      NaN
5  2021-05-01 08:00:56   65.0  VSFAALJS     APPAREL     15.0
6  2021-06-03 09:07:33   55.0  VSRANDOM      SPORTS      NaN
```